# Problems booting because the HDD is full. How can I get stuff off my hard drive?

Tags: boot, login, disk-usage

I have used up all the space on my hard drive and when starting up the computer says the only option I have is to start up in basic graphics mode. On the screen it then says

```
stopping system v runlevel compatibility
```

I have looked at the answers provided on here. Tt will let me type but then nothing else.

I tried the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> combination, but nothing happens. I have some stuff on the hard drive I need. Can I get that off at least? I am at a loss!

Answer (score 1):

Dont worry the stuff on your hard drive should be safe.

You have a few options. Sounds like you are not happy with the command line so we'll try something else.

If you have your installation CD you can use this as a boot disk, its slower to boot, but it will allow you to boot fully into ubuntu, and your hard disk will be mounted as a separate drive.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to go into this drive and delete some stuff from it that you dont need - make a bit of space.

Another alternative is to move some stuff to a thumb drive to create space on your drive. Remember that when booted from the CD your hard drive will temporarily have a different path. Something like /media/discname/home/yourusername perhaps.

After you have done this, remove the CD and you should then be able to boot as normal.

This assumes that you are correct in thinking that lack of disc space id the reason for your boot problems.

Comment: Thanks for that it is much appreciated!! The only problem is that i cant find my installation CD. Hopefully when/if i do my problem will be solved!!